# Adding android platform to a Ionic (Cordova) + Genymotion project in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: android, ionic-framework, cordova-3, genymotion

Here are my configurations:

```
OS: Ubuntu 14.04
Genymotion: 2.3.0
node: v0.10.25
npm: 1.3.10
cordova: 3.6.3-0.2.13
ionic: 1.2.7
```

After I created an Ionic project I tried adding the Android platform to it:

```
$ ionic start myApp sidemenu
...
$ cd myApp
$ ionic platform add android
Creating android project...

/home/mehran/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: Failed to run "android". Make sure you have the latest Android SDK installed, and that the "android" command (inside the tools/ folder) is added to your PATH.
    at /home/mehran/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:43:27
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:641:7)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:956:11)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:466:12)
Error: /home/mehran/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.3/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:743:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:810:5)
```

The problem is that there's no `android` in the installed Genymotion folder. Am I supposed to install the original android SDK as well?

It's mention worthy that the installed Genymotion starts the emulated android on its own perfectly.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you have to install the Android SDK. You can find it here: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

You also need to add the tools folder into your PATH. So that it can run the `android` command

Export it like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:<PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK>/tools
```

Replace `<PATH_TO_ANDROID_SDK>` with the absolute path to your Android SDK.

Answer (score 1):

before adding the android platform, you need you install the Android SDK. The Android SDK provides you the API libraries and developer tools necessary to build, test, and debug apps for Android.

In case you already installed the SDK try to update it to the latest version of the Android SDK Tools.